# codecvt_utf8 deprecation and the replacement consuming the file encoding (BOM)

Tags: c++, c++17, locale, deprecated

I have next function that reads file:

```
std::wstring ReadUtf8File( const fs::path& filePath )
{
    std::locale curLocale{ std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0xefbbbf, std::consume_header> };

    std::wifstream wif{ filePath, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in };
    wif.imbue( curLocale );
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    return wss.str();
}
```

This function is not only reading file using utf8 encoding according to the BOM,
but it also ignores the BOM offset at the beginning of the file.

The problem is that I could not figure out how to write it using templated new std::codecvt<...> to avoid deprecation.

Looking at the  header there is no
option like codecvt_mode which I definetely need. Please help solving this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: All of the `<codecvt>` types are deprecated. There is no standard replacement (yet?). You are better off using a 3rd party Unicode library instead.